# Nginx 1.7.9 with google pagespeed plugin giving error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I want to install nginx 1.7.9 with nginx pagespeed latest version. 
my environment is `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` `trusty` `nginx 1.7.9` `page speed 1.9.32.2`

config command was successful

```
  ./configure --add-module=/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx
```

for config : i am getting following output

```
     checking for zlib library ... found
     creating objs/Makefile

     Configuration summary

     + using system PCRE library
      + OpenSSL library is not used
      + using builtin md5 code

  + sha1 library is not found
  + using system zlib library

  nginx path prefix: "/usr/local/nginx"
  nginx binary file: "/usr/local/sbin/nginx"
  nginx configuration prefix: "/etc/nginx"
  nginx configuration file: "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
  nginx pid file: "/run/nginx.pid"
  nginx error log file: "/var/log/nginx/error.log"
  nginx http access log file: "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
  nginx http client request body temporary files: "client_body_temp"
  nginx http proxy temporary files: "proxy_temp"
  nginx http fastcgi temporary files: "fastcgi_temp"
  nginx http uwsgi temporary files: "uwsgi_temp"
  nginx http scgi temporary files: "scgi_temp"
```

while running make, i am getting following error.

```
/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/chromium/src -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/google-sparsehash/src -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/google-sparsehash/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/protobuf/src -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/re2/src -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/out/Release/obj/gen -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/out/Release/obj/gen/protoc_out/instaweb -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/apr/src/include -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/aprutil/src/include -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/apr/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -I /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/include/third_party/aprutil/gen/arch/linux/x64/include -I objs \
            -o objs/ngx_modules.o \
            objs/ngx_modules.c
    cc -o objs/nginx \
        objs/src/core/nginx.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_log.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_palloc.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_array.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_list.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_hash.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_buf.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_queue.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_output_chain.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_string.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_parse.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_inet.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_file.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_crc32.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_murmurhash.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_md5.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_rbtree.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_radix_tree.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_slab.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_times.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_shmtx.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_connection.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_cycle.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_spinlock.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_cpuinfo.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_conf_file.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_crypt.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_proxy_protocol.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_syslog.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_timer.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_posted.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_busy_lock.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_accept.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_connect.o \
        objs/src/event/ngx_event_pipe.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_time.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_errno.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_alloc.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_files.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_socket.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_recv.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_readv_chain.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_udp_recv.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_send.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_writev_chain.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_channel.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_shmem.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_process.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_daemon.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_setaffinity.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_posix_init.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_user.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_process_cycle.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_linux_init.o \
        objs/src/event/modules/ngx_epoll_module.o \
        objs/src/os/unix/ngx_linux_sendfile_chain.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_regex.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_request.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_parse.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_write_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_copy_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_variables.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_script.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_upstream_round_robin.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_parse_time.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_static_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_index_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_chunked_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_range_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_headers_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_busy_lock.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/ngx_http_postpone_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_charset_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_userid_filter_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_geo_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_map_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_split_clients_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_rewrite_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_scgi_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_memcached_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_empty_gif_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_browser_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_hash_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_ip_hash_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_least_conn_module.o \
        objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_upstream_keepalive_module.o \
        objs/addon/src/log_message_handler.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_base_fetch.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_caching_headers.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_fetch.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_gzip_setter.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_list_iterator.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_message_handler.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_pagespeed.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_rewrite_driver_factory.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_rewrite_options.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_server_context.o \
        objs/addon/src/ngx_url_async_fetcher.o \
        objs/ngx_modules.o \
        -lpthread -lcrypt -lstdc++ /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_pagespeed-1.9.32.2-beta/psol/lib/Release/linux/x64/pagespeed_automatic.a -lrt -pthread -lm -lpcre -lz
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/nginx-1.7.9'
    make -f objs/Makefile manpage
    make[1]: Entering directory `/data/nginx-1.7.9'
    sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/usr/local/nginx|" \
            -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/run/nginx.pid|" \
            -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/etc/nginx/nginx.conf|" \
            -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/var/log/nginx/error.log|" \
            < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/nginx-1.7.9'
```

can any help in getting this issue fixed ? i dont know what exactly this error is ?

Comment: What's the error? I don't see an error in the snippet that you posted, you may need to post more lines

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes i updated

Comment: I think your question is not a programming question, so you should ask on another site like SuperUser. But said that, why do you think there is an error? It looks like your build completed normally.

Comment: No After this make install also giving me some errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed . I just updated config before make